# Django models count children and grand children

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset, subquery, graph-traversal

In Django models I need help selecting count of children and count of grand children.
My models:

```
Parent:

Child:
 parent = models.Foreignkey(Parent)
GrandChild:
 child = models.Foreignkey(Child)
```

I did

```
Parent.objects.annotate(num_child =Count('child’), num_grandchild=Count('child__grandchild'))
```

With this, I get num_child is exactly same value as num_grandchild

Can you please help

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO! As a starter, I think you should write `Parent.objects.annotate(num_child =Count('child'), num_grandchild=Count('child__grandchild'))
`

Comment: If you didn't specify a `related_name` in your `ForeignKey`, you can try `Parent.objects.annotate(num_child =Count('child_set'), num_grandchild=Count('child_set__grandchild_set'))`

Comment: Thanks AlexandreS for the swift reply. I tried the above I still get the same count for both child and grand child. If I do separate queries on for Count(‘child’) and another for Count(‘child__grandchild’) I get them separately correct. But in the same query I fail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you must set distinct on the Count()

```
q = Parent.objects.annotate(num_child=Count('child', distinct=True), num_grand_child=Count('child__grandchild', distinct=True))
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/db/aggregation/#combining-multiple-aggregations

Comment: Worked like magic, thanks so much @Aprimus, adding distinct=True was the solve.